# Retrieve photo post details using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post, photo

How can I retrieve photo details using facebook graph APIs?

I know how to retrieve posts details using FB apis by calling this URL: `graph.facebook.com/<PostID>?accesstoken=AA`

What about photo posts whose URLs contain `photo.php`?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you are asking about Photos that has been posted on user wall. These photo posts are same as any normal post but **TYPE** field of such posts is **PHOTO**.

The attached photo can be retrieved using the **OBJECT_ID** field of this post.

Refer following link for more detail.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Answer (score 0):

It's the same:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[PHOTO_ID]?accesstoken=
```

[graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)